# Escape character in double quote string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried the example from the documentation about [special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6#escape-e):

```
$fgColor = 32 # green
"`e[${fgColor}mGreen text`e[0m"
```

Instead of "green Text" I get the following output: `e[32mGreen texte[0m`

[image]

If i try with a tab character, everything works as expected:

```
"`tThe Tab works"
```

[image]

As a workaround I found that the following works:

```
$Esc = [char]27
$fgColor = 32 # green
"$Esc[${fgColor}mGreen text$Esc[0m"
```

[image]

What is going on with the escape character in the example with green text from the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. `` `e `` is not an escape sequence for a special character in *Windows* PowerShell. Instead the other meaning of `` ` `` applies, which simply causes the following character to be interpreted verbatim (which does pretty much nothing for characters that are not special). Your workaround is sensible and has the benefit of actually working. For a one-off you could also use `$([char]27)` and avoid the variable.

PowerShell started out as a Windows shell and since the Windows console for a long time did not support ANSI escape sequences, `` `e `` wasn't really a very useful thing. In fact, I'd argue that a lot of the more-or-less default escapes we carry around since C are not really useful anymore.

PowerShell *Core* 6 (6.2.2 here) actually *does* support `` `e ``:

[image]